# Remove If Error through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this `vba` code to remove `#DIV/0!` errors.

```
Sub IFERROR()
Dim frange As Range, c As Range, ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Set frange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not frange Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In frange
            c.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Right(c.Formula, Len(c.Formula) - 1) & ","""")"
        Next c
    End If
    Set frange = Nothing
Next ws
End Sub
```

The above code is applying Iferror formula in all cells, can anybody help me to apply this `VBA` code to only cells which showing `#DIV/0!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `CVErr(xlErrDiv0)` is what you are looking for. You need to check if cell contains some error first, because comparing `CVErr(xlErrDiv0)` with cell value that doesn't contain error leads to, well... error :) .

```
Sub IFERROR()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set frange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not frange Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In frange
                If IsError(c.Value) Then
                    If c.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then
                        c.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Right(c.Formula, Len(c.Formula) - 1) & ","""")"
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        End If
        Set frange = Nothing
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: After running the above code in some cells i am getting this error #VALUE!, how to remove this

Comment: Maybe change on `c.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Or c.Value = CVErr(xlErrValue)`

Comment: Or, if you are willing to do change formula for every type of error, erase `c.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)` condition.